# Get the location id of a fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a fan page with an address.
Also, I can get the location details using the facebook API.

However, to create a new post with a `review button` I need the location id instead of the details.

[image]

I am using the following lines to create a `share button`:

```
var data = {
    message: 'Hi !',
    place: location_id
};

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', data, function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        console.error(response.error);
    } else {
        console.log(response.id);
    }
});
```

And it works if I use a specific location id. But I can't get the location id from a specific page.

Please give me some ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was falling asleep, but I got one idea.

And finally, that idea was the solution:

It is possible to **use the fan page id directly in the place parameter**. It can be used like a place id.